# Flagging NAA on an answer where they're trying to answer through comments

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255363/alignment-issue-in-aspx) a new user has submitted two answers that are exceptionally low quality, and should be comments... but it's the normal thing that they don't have the reputation to comment directly on the question.

I have flagged the [2nd of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255549/930393), but they've confused the situation by attempting to answer the question through the comments of the [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255465/930393).

I don't really want to flag the first answer as they're attempting to help the OP - just not in a manner that I believe they should - and I don't want that help to be deleted.

Should I flag the [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255465/930393)?

---

Turns out I probably should have, but doesn't matter now as both of the answers have been deleted.

Thank you to whichever mod was responsible.

Comment: Actually mods weren't involved, just 3 trusted users who saw this post. It's good you brought it up though, cause it's pretty hard to gather and convince 3 >=20K users to delete something.

Comment: Ah, fair enough @David, thanks for the info. Another feature to look forward to if I ever reach such heady heights :-)

Comment: If the question OP doesn't have 10K+ rep and the "answer" OP's comments would be good comments, you can consider commenting yourself on the question and re-posting the comments. To me, it doesn't seem like the comments that were posted as answer have any use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flagging as "not an answer" would be appropriate.

But you could also have edited the first post, by removing everything in it - it was not an answer but a comment. Then paste in the part from the comment which was actually an answer. Leave an edit remark "pasted answer from comments".

The edit remark is particularly important for low rep users who's edits have to go through edit review. Without the remark, the reviewers won't understand why there were such drastic changes to the post and reject the edit.